# JPA: Join Fetch results to NULL on empty many side

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, lazy-loading

I have a one to many relationship between User and GameMap. One user can have many maps.

**User class:**

```
// LAZY LOADED
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "creater")
private final List<GameMap> maps = new ArrayList<>();
```

However, sometimes I need to eager load the maps. To avoid the **LazyInitializationException** after closing Session, I have two variants of retrieving Users.

**User Repository:**

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    Optional<User> findById( Long id );

    @Query("SELECT u FROM User u JOIN FETCH u.maps WHERE u.id = (:id)")
    public User findByIdEagerFetch( @Param("id") Long id );
}
```

**Problem:**
However, the JPQL JOIN FETCH variant to eager load in one go the user and his maps returns a NULL user **if there are no maps for this user in the table**.

**Question:**
How can I rewrite the JPQL statement in order to retrieve the user and optionally(!) all his maps but if there are no maps, than thats okay, but dont return a NULL user.

Comment: Use "left join"

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A `FETCH JOIN` actually will resolve to an *inner* join in SQL.  This means that any records/entities in the `User` table which have no maps will be *removed* from the result set.  You need the `LEFT` keyword on your `FETCH JOIN` to get all the results, even those without a map.

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.maps WHERE u.id = (:id)")
public User findByIdEagerFetch( @Param("id") Long id );
```

Comment: In my case it did not work as I expected. I have one to many relationship, had exactly same problem.

I use identical JPQL, and if there's no related entities on "many" end the list of requested entities (like 'user' in example above) is returned orrectly.
But if a requested entity refers several related entities (e.g. user having 2 maps in the example) it's repeated several times, once for each related entity. Both in SQL result rows and in java objects.
I put 'distinct' to query and it fixed the problem but I wonder if I do it correctly and no problems will arise later.

Comment: @tequilacat distinct is specifically for such cases